# Sending mail with Android and C#, it never returns from SmtpServer.Send

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, smtp, smtpclient

I have the following code that works perfectly with C# and WPF:

```c
String emaailO = "xxxxxxx@outlook.com";
String passwordO = "123456789";
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(emaailO);
mail.To.Add(etEmailUser.Text);
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

mail.Body = "email body";
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emaailO, passwordO);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

I'm implementing the same thing with android and C#, but when the program reaches SmtpServer.Send it freezes on that line. No exception or some kind of error occurs.

[image]

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: All internet communication should be done in a thread.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I have also put it in an asynchronous task and the result is the same, it never comes out of that line of code. As I mentioned above, I have tested it in WPF and that doesn't happen.

It's like something needs to be activated, something related to communication with the internet even though the permissions are enabled in the manifest.

Comment: I have checked the code you provided on Xamarin.Forma Android project and Xamarin.Android project. Both of them work well. Could you provide more details for me to reproduce?

Comment: Could I make a simple example project and share it with you?

Comment: Someone else helped me test my code on another PC with VS and it works fine, it's something else on my computer.

Comment: The code is okay. I guess maybe something like firewall blocking some SMTP connections.